# Why is my ListView not Displaying?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a problem with a `ListView` that is not displaying. I get no error and background picture and other text are displaying but the `ListView` is not displaying. I can't find the error by debugging.

Any clue what the problem is?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    List<String> sermon;
    List<String> links;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ListView list;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        sermon = new ArrayList<String>();
        links = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sermon);           

        new PostTask(this).execute("http://gibk.se/sample-page/predikningar/?podcast");
    }

    public class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Long, String> {

        private Context context;

        public PostTask(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
        }

        private InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
            try {
                return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                String url = params[0];
                URL urls = new URL(url);

                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
                XmlPullParser xmlParser = factory.newPullParser();

                xmlParser.setInput(getInputStream(urls), "UTF_8");

                boolean insideItem = false;

                int eventType = xmlParser.getEventType();
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                            if (xmlParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                                    insideItem = true;
                            } else if (xmlParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                                    if (insideItem)
                                            sermon.add(xmlParser.nextText());
                        } else if (xmlParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("guid")) {
                                    if (insideItem)
                                            links.add(xmlParser.nextText());
                            }
                    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG
                                    && xmlParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                            insideItem = false;
                    }

                    eventType = xmlParser.next();
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                                long arg3) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(links.get(position));
                    String url = uri.toString();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output of logcat please.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a problem with a listView that is not displaying. I get no
>   error and background picture and other text are displying but the
>   listLiew is not displaying. I cant find the error by degugging.

If there is no error so most likely there can be two reasons why:

You are dynamically adding data to `ListAdapter` so in `onPostExecute()` or `onProgressUpdate(`) method try to call method on your `ListAdapter`

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

There is really chance that your `ListView` is not correctly refreshed, this method ensure it.

Your `ListView` can be empty. Try to log `XML parsing` whether you getting values correctly.

Comment: Yes, thats the error but I only get values from my XML parsing when I put it in the onCreate. But as soon as I move it to the doTnBackground method then my list becomes empty. Why is it so ?

Comment: How i wrote, try to log if you are getting any value from XML. If there is error, add here logcat...

Comment: no values from XML the boolean is always false and no error in logcat. BUT url is ok in the debugging. And the evantType Variable is either 2 or 4 for every loop

Comment: so problem is in XML parsing logic..try to use classic DOM Parser instead of XMLPullParser.

Answer (score 0):

Set your adapter after **AsyncTask** finish.

**onPostExecute**  Method

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sermon);
```

Comment: That doens make any differance

Comment: you can get no values from xml. so please debugging your xml parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter passed by the `onPostExecute` is get from the `doInBackground` method. So you may have to return the sermon from `doInBackground`. And also add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
This [link](http://code.google.com/p/makemachine/source/browse/trunk/android/examples/async_task/src/makemachine/android/examples/async/AsyncTaskExample.java) may help you.